# Dell M6400 100% CPU usage in Google Talk and Skype

Tags: cpu, skype, gmail

We've just upgraded the OS on a Dell M6400 from the factory Windows Vista x64 to Windows 7 x64.

Through observing with Process Explorer I have found that the system is experiencing close to 100% CPU usage when using Google Talk (video) and also Skype (video). We've used LogMeIn and GoToAssist in the past, but I'm not sure if this is the cause of the issue. The latest NVIDIA video drivers for the onboard card have been installed.

I'm aware that the Google Talk plugin (which is currently being used via Chrome) has some known issues, but Skype presents the same problem. I have seen the hardware interrupts seem to be a bit high in Process Explorer. Some people also blame the sound card for having a buggy driver.

Are there any other ideas on what we can do to track the problem down?

Comment: And what process is causing the high CPU Usage? Skype? Google Talk? Both in combination?

Comment: How to get the cause of high CPU usage by DPC (Deferred Procedure Call) and interrupts?...http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/140263-how-to-get-the-cause-of-high-cpu-usage-by-dpc-interrupt/

Comment: the google talk plugin for gmail, and also skype. i tested them independently as the machine is being used for video conferencing which is where the issue primarily manifests.